# using curl instead wget on docker image

Tags: linux, docker, curl, wget

we are using `wget` inside docker images which works ok and we want to switch to `curl` however it doesnt work

This is command before with wget

```
wget https://github.sme.corp/wiki-raw/dwi/bre/dists/stable/Key.gpg.key -O- | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://github.sme.corp/wiki-raw/dwi/bre/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bre.list && \
```

I try to change it to curl like following and it doesn't work ( I dont see the same output) , any idea what am I missing here?

```
curl -sSL -f -k https://github.sme.corp/wiki-raw/dwi/bre/dists/stable/Key.gpg.key | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://github.sme.corp/wiki-raw/dwi/bre/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bre.list && \
```

Comment: try with `curl -O` (it is upper-case O)

Comment: What output are you getting?  What behavior do you expect to see?

Comment: @Ntwobike - try that already without success

Comment: @DavidMaze - this is some custom output from the lib which I do the curl command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try curl command like below

```
curl -f -L -o <<weblink to the file>>
```